# Update is throwing DataException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using `async/await` on my `MVC` application and I get a `DataException` when calling `context.SaveChangesAsync()` (it even happens when not using async).

I implemented unit of work pattern found [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and I have tried everything, changing code, using sync instead, commenting lines of calls, etc. I'm out of ideas. My entities won't update. But they do get created thought.

Here's my piece of code:

```
// Inside POST EDIT
try {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        unitOfWork.StudentRepository.Update(student);
        await unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
} catch (DataException) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persist see your system administrator");
}

// Inside Repository -- It's a generic type defined as

// public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> 
// where TEntity : class { .......

public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
}

public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate) {
    dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
    context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

// Inside UnitOfWork
public Task<int> SaveAsync() {
    return context != null ? context.SaveChangesAsync() : Task.FromResult<int>(1);
}
```

**Update:** After doing so much research I found out people use a code snipped like this:

```
public void ApplyStateChanges()
{
    foreach (var dbEntityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        var entityState = dbEntityEntry.Entity as EntityBase;
        if (entityState == null)
            throw new InvalidCastException("All entites must implement the IObjectState interface, " +
                                           "this interface must be implemented so each entites state can explicitely determined when updating graphs.");

        dbEntityEntry.State = StateHelper.ConvertState(entityState.State);
    }
}
```

and call it before `SaveChangesAsync()`, do that has anything to do with the problem I'm facing?

**Update 2**: Here's what I get when I click [Copy exception detail to the clipboard](http://pastebin.com/AKaELhch).

I tried changing the code to use `TryToUpdateModel()` and it doesn't throw an exception, **but the data isn't updated anyway**

Comment: post the full exception and stack trace!

Comment: Please post the message from both the exception and it's inner exception (if such exists). The error *may* have nothing to do with your code and everything to do with a database not found or column mismatch between tables and your object.

Comment: I posted a link to my stack trace from the `DataException`, hope this help cause cause I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

Have you try asyncTransactionScope ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/data/dn456843.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I really hope no one else goes through this. So the issue was the following:

I was overriding `SaveChanges()` and `SaveChangesAsync()` on `DbContext` so that I can do a timestamp on every entity through an `ITimestamp` with `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate` properties.

Since when updating you don't modify the `CreatedDate`, it was getting a `null` value, and `C#` doesn't seems to allow null on `DateTime`.

So in order to fix it, I marketd it as non-modified like this inside my overriden save methods:

```
if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified) {
    Entry(entry.Entity as ITimestamp).Property(e => e.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
}
```